# How to use GroupBy in lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, group-by

I have a lookup column and i want to use groupby for that lookup column in rest api.
Anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: I didn't get you, what do you mean `groupby` for lookup column? Can you please explain by giving any example from you list data?

Comment: `/items?$select=Member/Title&$expand=Member&$groupby=Member_x003a_StatusCal` in this rest call Member:StatusCal is lookup column, Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

We can use CAML query with REST API to group by list items.

Example code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var listName="TestList";
    var fieldName="LookupField";
    var viewXml ="<View><Query><GroupBy Collapse='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='"+fieldName+"'/></GroupBy></Query></View>";

    var camlQuery={"query" :{"__metadata": { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }, "ViewXml": viewXml}};
    $.ajax({
        url:  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+ listName +"')/GetItems",                          
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(camlQuery),
        headers: { 
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
                 $("#Test").append("<p>"+item.Title+"</p>");
            });
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("Failed to get details");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="Test"/>
```